# Change values of bound form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a bound django form with a integer field which i eventually want to change. How can i access and change the values of a field in a form after binding but before rendering. I tried:

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    depth = forms.IntegerField(initial=0)
    def incDepth(self):
        self.fields['depth']=self.fields['depth']+1    

f=TestForm()
f.incDepth()
print f.as_table()
```

But i do not understand how to access the IntegerField value correctly....
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain your use case here? This seems an unusual thing to want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in form's init() method:

```
def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['depth'] = self.depth['fields'] + 1
```

Comment: i guess you mean: `self.fields['depth'] = self.fields['depth'] + 1` 
but then, same error (unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'IntegerField' and 'int'). Thats the point, this line does not work!

Comment: Ah! a typo error, but there is solution to this. let me add this in an edit.

Comment: @Cornelius: a quick question..would you mind adding a model for this and then use a model form?